# Passing results of an except to View (two attempts)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I've tried doing this multiple ways but come up empty each time. I'm trying to get the result of an Except between two queries and return the results back to the view.

**Attempt One:**

Write each of the queries and perform the except passing it to a view model and then to the view:

which results in the following error:

```
ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Object]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[EditDocumentation.ViewModels.MissingViewModel]'
```

## MissingObjects()

```
public IActionResult MissingObjects()
        {
            //var missing = from info in _context.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES_MANHATTANs
            //              select new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() { id = 0, Schema = info.Table_schema, Name = info.table_name };
            //var missing2 = from objects in _context.Objects
            //               select new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() { id = 0, Schema = objects.Schema, Name = objects.Name };
            //Dataset exceptdataset = new Dataset();
            //var set = exceptdataset.Except(missing, missing2);
            var missing = from info in _context.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES_MANHATTANs
                          select new { id = 0, Schema = info.Table_schema, Name = info.table_name };
            var missing2 = from objects in _context.Objects
                           select new { id = 0, objects.Schema, objects.Name };
            var set = missing.Except(missing2).Select(list => new MissingViewModel { id = list.id, Schema = list.Schema, Name = list.Name }).ToList();
            return View(set);
        }
```

## View

```
@model List<EditDocumentation.ViewModels.MissingViewModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MissingObjects";

}

<h1>MissingObjects</h1>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="tableFixHead">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Schema
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.Schema
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-controller="Objects" asp-action="Add" asp-route-objectschema="@item.Schema" asp-route-objectname="@item.Name">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

## Attempt Two

Created a class and a method to handle the data. I then pass this to the View and it appears to be working like I want it to but the Except() operation isn't working properly its returning all values from the first data set to the View. After doing some research it appears to be comparing two Objects which wont evaluate properly so i attempted to implement an IEqualityComparer<> but i dont really know how to use it.

Which results in the following error:

```
NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EditDocumentation.Models.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES_MANHATTAN]).Select(info => new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() {id = 0, Schema = info.Table_schema, Name = info.table_name}).Except(value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EditDocumentation.Models.Objects]).Select(objects => new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() {id = 0, Schema = objects.Schema, Name = objects.Name}), __p_0)': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except' is currently not supported.
```

## Class and Method

```
public class INFO_SCHEMA_DATA
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Schema { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

        }

        public class INFO_SCHEMA_DATA_EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<INFO_SCHEMA_DATA>
        {
            public bool Equals(INFO_SCHEMA_DATA x, INFO_SCHEMA_DATA y)
            {
                if (y == null && x == null)
                    return true;
                else if (x == null || y == null)
                    return false;
                else if (x.Name == y.Name && x.Schema == y.Schema
                                    && x.id == y.id)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            public int GetHashCode(INFO_SCHEMA_DATA obj)
            {
                return obj.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        //public class ObjectsData
        //{
        //    public int id { get; set; }
        //    public string Schema { get; set; }
        //    public string Name { get; set; }
        //}

        public class Dataset
        {
            public List<INFO_SCHEMA_DATA> Except(IQueryable<INFO_SCHEMA_DATA> info, IQueryable<INFO_SCHEMA_DATA> objects)
            {
                List<INFO_SCHEMA_DATA> list = info.Except(objects, new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA_EqualityComparer()).ToList();
                return list;
            }


        }
```

## MissingObjects()

```
public IActionResult MissingObjects()
        {
            var missing = from info in _context.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES_MANHATTANs
                          select new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() { id = 0, Schema = info.Table_schema, Name = info.table_name };
            var missing2 = from objects in _context.Objects
                           select new INFO_SCHEMA_DATA() { id = 0, Schema = objects.Schema, Name = objects.Name };
            Dataset exceptdataset = new Dataset();
            var set = exceptdataset.Except(missing, missing2);
            //var missing = from info in _context.INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES_MANHATTANs
            //              select new { id = 0, Schema = info.Table_schema, Name = info.table_name };
            //var missing2 = from objects in _context.Objects
            //               select new { id = 0, objects.Schema, objects.Name };
            //var set = missing.Except(missing2).Select(list => new MissingViewModel { id = list.id, Schema = list.Schema, Name = list.Name }).ToList();
            return View(set);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried use the ViewBag[] array rather than ViewData[]? In your html code you would just add "<h4>@ViewBag["Message"]</h4>"

Comment: The first error seems like a cast issue your model is a list of MissingViewModel` but you are returning a list of `Objects`, consider casting `var set` to `List<MissingViewModel>`, or better still loop through it and create you own model. let me know if this helps

Comment: @Bosco no success, when casting to `List<MissingViewModel>` it says cast is redundant as var set is already a `List<MissingViewModel>`